# For any positive integer $k$, are there always primes $p$ and $q$ such that $q-p=2^k$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, experimental-mathematics

Experimental evidence suggests to me that there are always primes $p$ and $q$ such that $q-p=2^k$.

Some examples include: $5-3=2$, $11-7=4$, $19-11=8$, $29-13=16$, $43-11=32$, etc.

I am now sure how to go about proving this. It seems like it should be accessible enough, perhaps using something like Dirichlet's theorem for primes ($a+bk$ is prime for infinitely many $k$ if $\gcd(a,b)=1$).

Can someone help me prove or disprove this?

Comment: [Related](https://oeis.org/A020483), this is the sequence of least primes $p$ such that $p+2n$ is also prime.  As you can see from the links there, little is known in general.

Comment: [Polignac's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) asserts that for any even integer $n$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p - q = n$.  This seems to suggest the answer to your question is yes, but I do not know of a proof.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but a few data points. The table shows the smallest solution for each power of $2$. As we can see, the smallest $q$ is usually pretty close to the power of $2$, that is, $p$ is quite small, but unfortunately not small enough to be predictable.

\begin{array}{rrrr}
k & 2^k & q & p \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 5 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 7 & 3 \\
3 & 8 & 11 & 3 \\
4 & 16 & 19 & 3 \\
5 & 32 & 37 & 5 \\
6 & 64 & 67 & 3 \\
7 & 128 & 131 & 3 \\
8 & 256 & 263 & 7 \\
9 & 512 & 523 & 11 \\
10 & 1024 & 1031 & 7 \\
11 & 2048 & 2053 & 5 \\
12 & 4096 & 4099 & 3 \\
13 & 8192 & 8209 & 17 \\
14 & 16384 & 16421 & 37 \\
15 & 32768 & 32771 & 3 \\
16 & 65536 & 65539 & 3 \\
17 & 131072 & 131101 & 29 \\
18 & 262144 & 262147 & 3 \\
19 & 524288 & 524341 & 53 \\
20 & 1048576 & 1048583 & 7 \\
21 & 2097152 & 2097169 & 17 \\
22 & 4194304 & 4194371 & 67 \\
23 & 8388608 & 8388619 & 11 \\
\end{array}

Comment: Perhaps one could start with the apparently easier question: when is $3+2^n$ a prime? See https://oeis.org/A057732.

Comment: I don't think we should be trying to make them predictable, checking the table with the examples provided by abnry, there are more than just one pair of primes that satisfy the equation

Answer (score 0):

**Claim**: Yes, there are always primes $(p,q)$ such that their difference is $2^k$ for all positive integers k.

**Idea**: Assume the contrary for some $k$. Then, for all primes p, $2^k+p$ is composite. By Green-Tao Theorem, primes contain arbitrarily large arithmetic progressions. Hence, for any positive integer $n$ there exists primes $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ such that they form an arithmetic progression. Then, $2^k+p_1,2^k+p_2,...,2^k+p_n$ also forms an arithmetic progression. Since we can get n sufficiently large, we can see by Dirichlet's theorem that there must exist one prime $p$ such that $2^k+p$ is prime. Hence, we have a solution, $(2^k+p,p)$. Contradiction.

Hence, for all positive integers $k$, there exists pirmes $(p,q)$ such that $p-q = 2^k$

Note that this is not a proof but suggest only why it might exist.

Comment: This suggest equally much that there are infinitely many prime gaps of size $1$...

Comment: An interesting idea. But I have one reservation. Probably due to me not being educated about the details of neither Dirichlet nor Green-Tao. When they produce longer and longer arithmetic progressions of primes, the interval of that progression may also grow, right? Are the error terms in Dirichlet then small enough to guarantee that you get a prime soon enough. You see, it is not sufficient that you get a prime eventually, because Green-Tao only promised a sequence of primes of length $n$.

Comment: How do you say that, barto?

Comment: Barto, what you said is not true as it does not follow the modular restrictions of Dirichlet's theorem. Please do think about what you are commenting about before you do so.

Comment: Besides, what I have given is not a proof but only a little intuition on why it is highly likely to be true.

Comment: You are right Jyrki Lahtonen, that is why I say that this is not a full proof but only an idea why it is highly likely to be true.